# Send "Button"-ID on Submit

Tags: php, forms, html-table, cell

I have an PHP page, which contains a form with some different input fields, e. g. day, month, year etc.. The form method is POST, only one non-editable field (The user ID) is sent via GET.
Of course, there is a "Submit"-Button, which triggers the form Action (PHP Script on Server).
The form tags contain a table with empty cells too. Now comes my question:

If the user clicks into one of the table cells, the form should be submitted, but additional to the regular form data the ID of the table cell should be transmitted too (If via POST or GET doesn't matter to me). How can I do that?

//Edit 2:

```php
...
<form method="post" action="<?= DOMAIN?>/.../addUserTimetable.php?uid=<?= $user->getUserID() ?>">
  <select id="day" name="day">
    ...
  </select>
  ...
  <input name="yearend" id="yearend" ...>
  <button type="submit">...</button>
  <table class="bordered">
    <tr>
      <th>Std.</th>
      <th>Montag</th>
      <th>Dienstag</th>
      <th>Mittwoch</th>
      <th>Donnerstag</th>
      <th>Freitag</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
      for($i=1; $i<13;$i++) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>".$i. "</th>";
        for($j=1;$j<6;$j++) {
          echo "<td id='h".$i. "d".$j. "' onclick='???'></td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
      }
    ?>
  </table>
</form>
...
```

The server sided procession is fine, but I haven't got any ideas - even after two hours google - how I could transmit the cell id additionally.

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific ?

Comment: @Akshay I tried to ;) Edited.

Comment: could you show us your code?

Comment: And do you want the form to send directly when the user clicks the table cell (as if it was a button) or do you still want the user to have to click the submit button?

Comment: @Christoffer Of course, added snippet. With clicking the cell, the user shall be led to a page, where he edits the cell content, this page is written and works fine. But for not loosing the other input data, the form has to be sent already, when the user clicks on a cell. When clicking, the form submit action should be done and after that the cell edit action opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be to hard. Have a look at the following example:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="something">

    <table>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="cel1">
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="cel2">
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input type="submit" name="cel13">
       </tr>
    </table>

    <input type="submit" value="save"> 
</form>
```

By giving the submit buttons in the table cells a name attribute, that name will also be present as a key on the `$_REQUEST`. Go ahead and var_dump the $_REQUEST and you'll see you can find out in the backend which button got pushed by checking which key exists.

Note that POST / GET is completely irrelevant here, both will work just the same. And obviously you could apply some css to those buttons to make them transparent and lay them on top of the table cells, so they don't look like buttons, but just "capture" the user's click.

One last side note, are you sure you want to send the userID as a GET parameter? That would be very easy for someone with bad intentions to manipulate. Consider not sending the ID at all, but keeping it in the session on the server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, sending the user ID as get seems unsafe but isn't. In the form action, the logged-in-users permissions are checked. Some users are allowed to change other users timetables.

Comment: Forgot to say: The uid is NOT the ID of the editing user, but the ID of the user whose timetable is added.

Comment: Yeah, I already got that from your update. You're probably save then (I suppose this is only accessible for authenticated users anyway). Just wanted to put a little warning out there. The things you see on the internet...

Comment: Your answer seems to work. Now, in the server script, I don't want to check POST for any possible combination, because the length of the timetable should vary in the future. How can I check POST for any sent variables excluding the ones that I have checked already (Via field name, these fields are post_required).

Comment: `array_diff(array_keys($_REQUEST), ["the", "keys", "that", "are", "always", "present"])`